# How to put ads inside videos just like youtube does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, backend, ads

I have a video streaming service built in nodejs and now i want to put ads inside those videos just like youtube does?

I tried searching for it but didn't found anything solid to start with. If anyone know about it then please help me out by giving me some overview about this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as complicated as it seems.  It's just another element that plays instead of the main content video element.  This is all done client-side.  There is nothing you need to do server-side.